# this.each and IE6-7

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've wrote a jQuery plugin for a project and it works perfectly in all browsers but IE6-7.

I found the problem, it's in this line:

```
return this.each(function(index) {  my_code  })
```

*.each* doesn't work in IE6-7 properly. This bug was fixed in the latest jQuery versions but I stack with 1.4.2 and can't update it. How can I rewrite it? Apparently I can't do this

```
return for ( var index=0; i<this.length; i++ ) {
```

or this

```
for ( var index=0; i<this.length; i++ ) { return
```

but there should be some way around.

Comment: Could you include your javascript errors?

Comment: @Kyle There are no errors. It's just that _each_ works only once in IE

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr Tell it to my employer and to thousands of IE6 users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You identified the current jQuery fixed IE 6-7 issues.  How about rewriting the `jQuery.each` function in your own script

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/7q94J/

```
jQuery.extend({
    each: [1.6.2 each function here]
});
```

Comment: The beauty of Javascript is that you can monkeypatch deficiencies in whatever library you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var l = this.length;
var i = 0;
var results = []
for(i=0; i<l; i++){
   results.push( ... )
}

return results;
```

Comment: There are a bunch of functions and event bindings there. Will it work?